# How to transform points to a "uniform distribution" over an $n$-cube?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, manifolds, computational-geometry, optimal-transport

I don't know if this is a well-studied problem (I hope it is!):

Suppose I have some points {$X_i\}$ that are generated from a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example. We do not know this probability distribution's analytical form. It could be uniform over a convex set, or just a $2$-D Gaussian distribution.

Is there a method that maps these points to some points $\{X^\prime_i\}$ within the $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ $2$-D cube, so that it looks like these transformed points are generated from a uniform distribution on $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$.

I know the very last part of my question is not quite rigorous (what do I mean by close to a uniform distribution?), but does anyone know which field I should look into to get any hints on this type of question? Thanks.

Comment: [I will represent your points by $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2,Y_2), \ldots$.] If the two components of the bivariate distribution are independent, then plugging each point $(X_i, Y_i)$ into the marginal CDFs $(F_X(X_i), F_Y(Y_i))$ will produce a uniform random variable on $[0,1]^2$. I am not sure how to generalize this to the non-independent case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone is interested. The above question is well-studied in the field of optimal transport. Suppose my ultimate goal is transforming an unknown distribution (but I can sample from) to a, say, uniform distribution. Then all I need to do is sample a bunch of samples from the two distributions and find the optimal transport between them.

For example, in this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-49/issue-2/Minimax-estimation-of-smooth-optimal-transport-maps/10.1214/20-AOS1997.short) the authors discuss some methods of estimating such a mapping using wavelet and Gaussian kernel.